# Docusaurus beginner : customizing sidebar entries

Tags: sidebar, docusaurus

beginner on docusaurus, I want to start writing doc folders : having [autogenerated](https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/sidebar#sidebar-item-autogenerated) sidebar by defaut, just  trying to remove or rename demonstration folders bring the following error, can't find why

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@site/docs/tutorial-basic/congratulations.md' in .....my-website/.docusaurus'`

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, and fixed it by

1. Terminate your docusaurus Project in terminal by "cmd+c";
2. reBuild your docusaurus Project by "yarn start";

Also, if it doesn't work, please check the file called "docusaurus.config.js" in your Project root path. Make sure you have the correct "themeConfig" setting. You can also find the instruction on how to modify your "themeConfig" in the [docusaurus documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/configuration)